# UIView - How to get notified when the view is loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, viewdidload

Is there anything similar to the `viewDidLoad` of `UIViewController` for a `UIView`???
I need to be notified as soon as a `UIView` has loaded (Subclass of `UIView`), and perform some actions.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Depending on what kind of actions you need to perform, there are several techniques:

1. `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` - UIView's designated
   initializer; always sent to a UIView to initialize it, unless the
   view is loaded from a nib;
2. `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder` - always sent to initialize a UIView whenever the view is loaded from a nib;
3. `-(void)awakeFromNib` - sent after all the objects in the nib are initialized and connected; applicable only if you load the object from a nib; you must call super;
4. `-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview` - sent immediately before the view is added as a subview to another view; `newSuperview` may be nil when you remove the view from its superview;
5. `-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow` - sent immediately before the view (or its superview) is added to a window; `newWindow` may be nil when you remove the view from a window;
6. `-(void)didMoveToSuperview` - sent immediately after the view is inserted into a view hierarchy;
7. `-(void)didMoveToWindow` - sent immediately after the view gets its window property set.  -

Basically, you can choose to perform your actions during initialization (1 & 2), after loading from a nib (3), before insertion into a view hierarchy (4 & 5) and after that (6 & 7).

Comment: Thanks a lot perfect answer (very detailed). I was modifying a segmented control and it wasn't displaying the changes because I was calling the modification method during init, I moved it to didMoveToWindow and it fixed all the problems

Comment: It seems all of this happened before viewDidLoad in viewController

Comment: `-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview` was the cure to all my problems, thank you very much!

Comment: I forgot again that some things do not work if you keep caling them inside a UIView at the very beginning of the initialization process.....
So doing it in 7 or performing with delay from there will always work! :)