# UIView's methods when it is loaded/visible and unloaded/disappeared

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am building a custom control, in which I want to register control (subclass of `UIButton`) for notification when it is loaded, and unregister when `UIView` is unloaded.

I have searched a lot, and found numerous methods for `UIViewController's` life cycle but not for simple `UIView.Can` you provide methods when I can determine start and end of `UIView`

Comment: Did you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4501974/2791407

Comment: Above link is very detailed for loading part of UIView lifecycle, but it do not addresses unloading or end of it.

Comment: Yep you're right, but it can be a starting point.

Comment: Also, if you are making a custom control then it might make sense to subclass `UIControl` instead. (this is not an answer to your question, just a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about registering for notifications when the control is created (with initWithFrame and initWithCoder) and deregistering when the control is destructed (in dealloc). You can then check for self.window at every notification to see if the control is visible.