# Is there any viewDidAppear method for UIView (not UIViewController)?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I need to understand when UIView appears on the screen, so I need an analogue of the viewDidAppear method.

I found a UIView lifecycle:

1. willMoveToSuperview
2. invalidateIntrinsicContentSize
3. didMoveToSuperview
4. awakeFromNib
5. willMoveToWindow
6. needsUpdateConstraints
7. didMoveToWindow
8. setNeedsLayout
9. updateConstraints
10. layoutSubviews
11. drawRect

I tried all of these methods, but I didn't get an answer.

Comment: no there is not but you can use custom delegates to call the viewDidApppear present on your ViewController

Comment: no.. there is no any such method..

Comment: Hi Alexander, `viewDidAppear` is the method in `UIViewController`. We could have find proper solution, if you share what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @LalKrishna, thanks. I need a variable that shows that UIView has appeared.

Comment: @AlexanderGalkin - I have added more relevant tags to this question. Please approve the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No there is no `viewDidAppear` in `UIView`. you may override func `drawRect` to do any UI changes that you need on `UIView` inherited View.

**SideNote** - In case you want get `drawrect` to update at later times, Call `setNeedsDisplay`. `setNeedsDisplay`will not immediately call `drawRect` but marks the receiver’s entire bounds rectangle as needing to be redrawn.

In other words - You should never call drawRect yourself. Instead, you tell the system that drawing needs to be done by using the setNeedsDisplay method, which marks the view as dirty. And the drawRect method of the subclass would then be called during the next update cycle.

*As per the queries from OP(@Alexander), he just need to set some variable so it advisable to use any of the following override functions, depending on action need to be performed*

- `-(void)didMoveToSuperview` - sent immediately after the view is
  inserted into a view hierarchy.
- `-(void)didMoveToWindow` - sent immediately after the view gets its
  window property set.
- `-(void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview` - sent
  immediately before the view is added as a subview to another view;
  `newSuperview` may be nil when you remove the view from its
  superview.
- `-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow` - sent immediately
  before the view (or its superview) is added to a window; `newWindow`
  may be nil when you remove the view from a window.

Comment: thanks! I need a variable that indicates that a UIView has appeared. If I override the func drawRect and set the variable to true, will it be correct?

Comment: Though this will work but just to set a variable calling drawRect is not a good idea. You may use 'willMoveToSuperview' or 'didMoveToSuperview' for this purpose. What is the purpose of this variable ?

Comment: This link have a nice description of when each of the methods gets called. You may use it which suits your purpose.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502761/8238512

Answer (score 1):

Look, `viewDidAppear` is method of `UIViewController` which represents moment when `view` of ViewController did appear and allows you to do declare what should happen.

`UIView` has no method like this. This comes from MVC pattern: controller is in this case `UIViewController` which controls changes, actions, etc., and `view` is just what controller shows.